# Change property value of all elements in array but need only one

Tags: javascript, arrays

I create `users2` array that has 2 elements. I want to change property value of only one element. The output should be 2 2 2 5, but it is 2 2 5 5, so I change property value of all elements in array.

```js
var users2 = [];
var fieldArray = [];
users2.push({"id": 0}, {"id": 1});
fieldArray.push([{text: "2"}, {text: "2"}, {text: "2"}]);
users2[0].arrShow = fieldArray;
users2[1].arrShow = fieldArray;

console.log(users2[0].arrShow[0][0].text);
console.log(users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text);

users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text = "5";

console.log(users2[0].arrShow[0][0].text);
console.log(users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two user objects are both using the **same** `arrShow` (which is also accessed via `fieldArray`), and thus using the **same** 0th entry of the 0th entry in that array. Naturally, changing the state of that object is reflected regardless of which path you take to look at that object.

Instead, give your users *separate* `arrShow`s with *separate* objects in them:

```js
var users2 = [
  {
    id: 0,
    arrShow: [
      [{text: "2"}, {text: "2"}, {text: "2"}]
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    arrShow: [
      [{text: "2"}, {text: "2"}, {text: "2"}]
    ]
  }
];

console.log(users2[0].arrShow[0][0].text);
console.log(users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text);

users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text = "5";

console.log(users2[0].arrShow[0][0].text);
console.log(users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text);
```

Or doing it separately after initialization:

```js
var users2 = [
  {id: 0, arrShow: []},
  {id: 1, arrShow: []}
];
users2[0].arrShow.push(
  [{text: "2"}, {text: "2"}, {text: "2"}]
);
users2[1].arrShow.push(
  [{text: "2"}, {text: "2"}, {text: "2"}]
);

console.log(users2[0].arrShow[0][0].text);
console.log(users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text);

users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text = "5";

console.log(users2[0].arrShow[0][0].text);
console.log(users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text);
```

Or if you need to base `arrShow` on a separate `fieldArray`, you need to copy both `fieldArray` and the objects in it; you can do that with `Array#map` and `Object.assign` (which is newish, but readily polyfilled for older environments):

```js
var users2 = [
  {id: 0, arrShow: []},
  {id: 1, arrShow: []}
];
var fieldArray = [{text: "2"}, {text: "2"}, {text: "2"}];

users2.forEach(function(user) {
  user.arrShow.push(
    fieldArray.map(function(entry) {
      return Object.assign({}, entry);
    })
  );
});

console.log(users2[0].arrShow[0][0].text);
console.log(users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text);

users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text = "5";

console.log(users2[0].arrShow[0][0].text);
console.log(users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but if I need to do it dynamically? How to "push" arrShow into users[0], users[1] etc?

Comment: @Tryam: You push *separate* arrays, instead of pushing the same array twice. I've updated the answer to add an example of that.

Comment: @Tryam: Added a third example copying `fieldArray` and its contents, assuming it's okay to make a **shallow** copy of each of the objects in `fieldArray`.

Comment: @Tryam: No worries. My bad, took me a moment to realize you needed to start out with `fieldArray`.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably wanting to avoid repetitive code, and have assumed that assignment will implicitly create a deep copy for you. That's not what happens.

To create a standard object structure, create a function that returns a whole new set of objects.

```
function makeUser(id) {
  return {
    id: id,
    arrShow: [
      [{text: "2"}, {text: "2"}, {text: "2"}]
    ]
  };
}
```

Then invoke it when you need a new set of data.

```
var users2 = [
  makeUser(0),
  makeUser(1),
];
```

Now mutating one user's data will no longer affect the other.

---

Here's a demo:

```js
var users2 = [
  makeUser(0),
  makeUser(1),
];

console.log(users2[0].arrShow[0][0].text);
console.log(users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text);

users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text = "5";

console.log(users2[0].arrShow[0][0].text);
console.log(users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text);

function makeUser(id) {
  return {
    id: id,
    arrShow: [
      [{text: "2"}, {text: "2"}, {text: "2"}]
    ]
  };
}
```

---

This can also be done with constructor functions or the ES6 `class` syntax.

```js
class User {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.arrShow = [
      [{text: "2"}, {text: "2"}, {text: "2"}]
    ];
  }
}

var users2 = [
  new User(0),
  new User(1),
];

console.log(users2[0].arrShow[0][0].text);
console.log(users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text);

users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text = "5";

console.log(users2[0].arrShow[0][0].text);
console.log(users2[1].arrShow[0][0].text);
```